# Why I am getting database size as 3072 in file explorer of android application

Tags: android

After creating SQLite database connection, while running when I view DDMS, file explorer shows the size of database as 3072.

I think that why I am unable to open the database and retrive the values. Can help me out to sort out this error?

Answer (score 0):

How big should the database be? If it's less than 3072 bytes it could be larger on disk due to the block size of the filesystem.

Comment: i think what u meant to say i didn't understand